# Queue discipline for a wireless interface is not set up

Tags: networking, optimization, kernel

I have 3 interfaces:

```
enp2s0 <- physical ethernet interface                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
lo <- loopback                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
wlp3s0 <- wireless ethernet interface
```

and `tc qdisc show`:

```
qdisc noqueue 0: dev lo root refcnt 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
qdisc fq_codel 0: dev enp2s0 root refcnt 2 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5.0ms interval 100.0ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn                                                                                                                                           
qdisc noqueue 0: dev wlp3s0 root refcnt 2
```

Why does `wlp3s0` have no discipline queue?  I mean the last `noqueue` line. How to interpret it?